# Getting URLs and Titles from a Google search

Tags: http, url, google-search

What's the simplest way to get the URL's and Titles from a given Google search term?  I only want to do this once, with a specific term, and I want to get all the URLs/Titles, not the first 10.  If there's a way to get the response delimited (e.g. in CSV format) that'd  be ideal.

I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel, but if that's necessary I'm game to do it (I'm on a Windows box and I can script in PHP).  I'm just looking for the fastest most reliable, common way of doing this..

**Update:** The suggestions thus far seem to require a modest amount of coding, both to parse HTML/XML, and to cycle through result sets (upping the start variable, to click "next").  Isn't there an existing program out there to quickly do this?

Comment: **ALL the urls??** Even the phrase "get titles and urls from google search" (without quotes) returned about [13,900,000](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=get+titles+and+urls+from+google+search&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&psj=1&fp=1&cad=b) results...

Comment: Only 894 results for this search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  You say you know PHP, so why not use cURL and some regular expressions?

```
<?php
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com/search?q=[search term here]&start=0");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
?>
```

The resulting source will be in $data. From that point you can use [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to gather the URLs you need and store them in an array.  Alternatively, you could try an [XML parser](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) for a cleaner approach.

Note that you can modify the start=0 to return additional results.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to click "next" using the cURL method?  That seems like it would take some time to code

Comment: Set start in the query string to an integer value. You can see how it affects the results by pasting the querystring into your browser and modifying it: http://www.google.com/search?q=test&start=10  (Note that this takes you to page two of the results)

Answer (score 0):

You can return xml data from a google search:

Check out http://www.google.com/cse/docs/resultsxml.html#XML_Results_for_Regular_and_Advanced_Search_Queries

Comment: It says the limit on num is 20.  I'd have to code a program to parse the XML and then cycle through.   Isn't there an existing program to do this?

Comment: That's only for the paid Site Search Engien, minimum $100 per year.